# Assign names to variables with condition

Tags: r, if-statement, variables

I would like to assign a "name" to a variable if a condition is met.

```
x 
1 
1
2
3
3
4
4
```

Then i would like to rename the variable in my df. For example changing all variables than range from 1 to 3  into "a".

```
Outcome
  x 
"a"
"a"
"a"
"a"
"a"
"b"
"b"
```

I have tried this code:
df$x <- ifelse(df$x >=1 & df$x <=3, "a")
I get the following error:
argument no is missing with no default

I dont know how to fix that.

Comment: what is `zip` variable.  Do you need `ifelse(cllw$x >=1 & cllw$zip <=3, "a", "b")`

Comment: @akrun oh this ois by wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ifelse` argument is

> ifelse(test, yes, no)

In the OP's post, 'test' and 'yes' are provided, and 'no' is not

```
ifelse(df$x >=1 & df$x <=3, "a", "b")
```

Or if we want to replace only for the condition

```
ifelse(df$x >=1 & df$x <=3, "a", df$x)
```

Or more easily

```
df$x[df$x >=1 & df$x <=3] <- 'a'
```

Or with `replace`

```
replace(df$x, df$x >=1 & df$x <=3, "a")
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(x  = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4))
```

Comment: is there another way without a no possibility, since i only want to assign one value maybe without the ifelse? i am only familiar with that one

Comment: @Lisam  What would be the other value 'b'?

Comment: @Lisam You can use `ifelse(df$x >=1 & df$x <=3, "a", df$x)`

Comment: i dont really have another b, rather multiple other options, like if a is not fulfilled it might be b,c,d, etc

Comment: i can upvote in 4 minutes, that is why i have not done it yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215544/discussion-between-lisam-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

If there are only two values that you need to assign you can do this without `ifelse` :

```
c('b', 'a')[(df$x >= 1 & df$x <= 3) + 1]
#[1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b"
```

If there are lot of conditions that you need to check you can do this using `case_when` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 mutate(new_x = case_when(between(x, 1, 3) ~ "a", 
                          #Add more conditions
                          TRUE ~ "b"))
```